# Невозможность нормального удаления приложения через лаунчер девайса

Tags: android, android-sdk

Есть приложение, на всех аппаратах удаляется нормально, но от владельцев `Asus` `Zenfone` разных моделей я получаю отзывы, к примеру:

> Интересно придумал, приложение удалить нельзя, значок при удалении на
>   весь экран!.

Естественно этого нельзя провернуть силами самого приложения (без рут-прав), проблема в девайсе. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

[image]
[image]

При удалении остальных приложений:

[image]

Comment: Попросите и у пользователей скриншот, будет понятнее

Comment: @iamtihonov Добавил в вопрос

Comment: Интересно однако, попахивает вирусом. Как я предполагаю это происходит при отображении диалога об удалении приложения. Скорее всего это нужно пользователю удалить все левые приложения или прошивка может быть у них с вирусом сторонняя.

Comment: @iamtihonov Я подозревал что в диалоговое окно пихается полная иконка (512×512), поэтому собрал на тест с максимальным разрешением в 192×192, но ситуация повторилась...

Comment: @iamtihonov Добавил в вопрос скрин удаления ВК, там всё нормально...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение нашлось.
Т.к. мне было лень делать иконку под разные размеры экрана, я использовал только одну. (620×620)
Как я понял, родной лаунчер на асусовской прошивке берет иконку не подгоняя её под нужные размеры...
Порезав иконку я получил то, что хотел - нормальное диалоговое окно при удалении:
[image]